# Configure Gradle test execution order

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5

In my Spring Boot app I have a suite of Gradle tests that I can run with `./gradlew test`. Is there a way I can run one package of tests before all the others, e.g. `com/example/myapp/firstpackage/**`.

I know that I can run *only* these tests with the following config

```
test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  include 'com/example/myapp/firstpackage/**'
}
```

But what I actually want to do is run the tests in this package at the beginning of the task, and then run the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Can not do this in Junit 5.

you have to switch to junit 4 - execution wise.

one way to do this is

1. create a TestSuite class - basic list of test classes
   see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("JUnit Platform Ordered Suite ")
@SelectClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class, Test3.class, Test4.class})
public class TestOrderedSuite {
}
```

2. change the gradle test from useJUnitPlatform to useJunit

```
dependencies {
    testCompileOnly 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.7.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.7.0'

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
//    useJUnitPlatform()
    useJUnit()
}
```

Comment: I have too many dependencies on JUnit 5 for this to be viable in my case

Answer (score 0):

add a test task (lets call it smoke tests) and let the default test task depend on it

```
task smokeTest(type: Test) {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  include 'com/example/myapp/firstpackage/**'
}

test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
   exclude 'com/example/myapp/firstpackage/**'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The classes in `com/example/myapp/firstpackage/**` will be run twice, first by `smokeTest` and then by `test`. They will fail in the latter case.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't really work because the tests in firstpackage are run in a separate task to the rest. This will result in 2 separate Junit test reports, code coverage reports, etc. So I need to run all the tests in the same task, but run those in firstpackage first